# Memory leak with NSNumber

Tags: iphone

Insruments swho to me a leak in my NSNumber.
Do you see any leak in my code please ? thanks

```
NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:aFloat];
[dictionary setValue:value forKey:@"aKey"];
```

Comment: Voted to close this question as too localized. There's also likely a dupe out there somewhere, as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you never release `dictionary` there is no memory leak there.  Instruments isn't always correct when it comes to detecting leaks.

Comment: Thanks, i am reating my dictionnary like this :  NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];..... return dictionary;

Comment: @samir - Then all of your objects are autoreleased and there should be no leak.  Unless somewhere else you are calling `retain`, or unless you are running this code on its own background thread and haven't set up an `NSAutoreleasePool` for it.